# How to connect android device to specific AP with adb shell or monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python, android-intent, android-emulator, monkeyrunner

I am trying to connect an android device to specific AP without keycodes. I am looking for adb shell commands or monkeyrunner script that can perform the same.
Hope you guys can help me with this.

PS. After researching for days only way I found is using wpa_cli in adb shell. But couldnt exactly connect because I was not able to find the exact codes.

Answer (score 0):

wpa_cli should work.Open wpa_cli>>
    add_network
    set_network  ssid "APSSID"
    set_network  key_mgmt NONE \if ap is confgrd in open none
    save_config
    enable 
these set of commands should work if WiFI is ON in UI.
using Monkeyrunner navigate using keycode is the only option OR 
you need to make an APK for ur specific operations